# Excel Schedule to work with hours

Tags: excel, vba, date, schedule

I am trying to write a formula ( or a vba code, because I am going to import that code to vba anyway ) to calculate dates with the given work hours.

There will be 2 main variables;
Work-Time ( hour ): how many hours is the given job on that row is gonna take.
Work-Date ( date ): is the planned date for that job to start.

And this calculations will be made for thousands of rows.

Right now formula is really basic, something like this: workday(A2;Sum(A2:$A$2))
The problem is, A2 ( which is work-time in hours ) is a number can be between 0,1 to up to hundreds of hours.
As you can see the problem, with each row, sum number increases and it gives enormous numbers. And if I don't fix the starting date, the date is almost never correct because the work-time can be short then 7 hours or much then 7 hours.

My main goal in here is to increase the work-date when the total work-time for each work-date passes 7 hours, and transferring the extra hours or minutes to the next work-date.

So it should look like this;

Work-time--------------- work-date

2 -------------------------  01.01.2017

4 -------------------------  01.01.2017

3 -------------------------  02.01.2017

4 -------------------------  02.01.2017

2 -------------------------  03.01.2017

Work-time is coming from another part of vba, and work-date is should be auto calculated. ( I am going to give the first starting date )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I customized cumulative work-time column idea and found a solution.

For row 15, I used this formula for cumulative work-time column;

```
=IF(K15>7;SUM(K15;MOD(L14;7));IF(L14>7;SUM(K15;MOD(L14;7));SUM(L14;K15)))
```

Again for row 15, I used this formula for workdate;

```
=WORKDAY(M14;(L15/7))
```

With these formulas, work-date function works great.
Thanks for the cumulative work-time idea!

Answer (score 0):

You may think of adding a cumulative work-time column, which will keep increasing but once total is greater than 7, it will start all over.

The work-date column can then use this information and once the total is `> 7`, it will move to the next workday.

So you may put:

- Formula in cell B2 - `=IF(SUM(B1,A2)>7,A2,SUM(B1,A2))`
- Formula in cell C3 - `=IF(SUM(B3,A4)>7,WORKDAY(C3,1),C3)`

And then copy it to rest of the rows below.

[image]

**Note:** the assumption is that your VBA puts a maximum of 7 hours in one row and in case the work-time is more, it carries forward the remaining balance to the next row. If the VBA is not doing so, additional formula is needed in the Work-time column to tackle that issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with these formulas, B column only increases with 2 rows. So if I get the 7 hours with 5 rows ( like 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 hrs ), then it doesn't work correctly, and C column formula is not correct. It refers to itself.

Comment: are u sure u followed the directions exactly? u might want to take a look into this uploaded sample:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13HXGzG60Jyom3AOrpqjbpSweQO6C63fzNhGkXKWZq5Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So the formulas you've written abouve actually is gonna be at B3, and C4, but what if a "work-time" at A column is more then 7? With B formula you've written, it's gonna be written directly, if it's more than 7. But let's say if cell A5 is 22 or even 100, then it should add 3 workdays to the schedule.

Comment: For 100, ofcourse it should add more then 3 days :)

Comment: Also, for the formula at the B row, it gives only 2 options; either the sum is lower then 7, then sum, or sum is greater then 7, then normal work-time. But if the sum is let's say 10, then there should be a plus 3 for the next day's value.